# Vue.js v-attr="expression"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using vue.js, I'm trying to **disable** a button if the qty of the item is less than 1.

```
<div v-repeat = "item: itemsList">
<button v-attr="disabled: {{item.qty}} < 1"> Click </button>
......
```

It is not working, nothing is being displayed at all. However, when I put a normal expression like:

```
<div v-repeat = "item: itemsList">
<button v-attr="disabled: 0 < 1"> Click </button>
......
```

It's working properly!

Can anyone explain why I'm unable to use the property in my condition? and is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<button v-attr="disabled: item.qty<1"> Click</button>
```

Demo fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/721/

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I'm using laravel which uses blade, so i'm used to {{}} to echo data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not working not because laravel conflicts with {{}} syntax but because inside the v-attr directive you don't need the handlebars syntax for the value because it will evaluate the expression directly.

On a side note if you are using laravel and need to show something within brackets use @{{}}. The '@' tells blade to ignore that expression so the vue instance can take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

For retification on Ivan's answer, syntax has since changed so I updated the fiddle accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/1734/

```
<div id="demo" v-for="item in itemlist">
    <button :disabled="item.qty < 1"> Click</button>
</div>
```

[Edit] This now works for Vue 2.0+

```
<div id="demo">
   <button v-for="item in itemlist" :disabled="item.qty < 1"> Click</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2022/